# WebBrowser set cookies or session on a new TabPage

Tags: c#, .net, session, cookies, browser

I want to recreate a web browser with tab capability, popup block and redirection to a new tab. 
Here what I've been able to reach:

```
firstTabWebBrowser.Navigate("www.site-with-popup.com"); //inizializa my broeser navigation

//...

(firstTabWebBrowser.ActiveXInstance as SHDocVw.WebBrowser).NewWindow3 += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow3EventHandler(Browser_NewWindow3); //new window 3 event    

//...

private void Browser_NewWindow3(ref object ppDisp, ref bool Cancel, uint dwFlags, string bstrUrlContext, string bstrUrl)
{

Cancel = true; //block a new IE window to be opened

TabPage addedTabPage = new TabPage("redirected tab"); //create new tab
tabControl_webBrowsers.TabPages.Add(addedTabPage); //add new tab to the TabControl
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser newTabWebBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser() //create new WebBrowser inside the new tab
{
   Parent = addedTabPage,
   Dock = DockStyle.Fill
};

System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser actualWebBrowser = (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser)tabControl_webBrowsers.SelectedTab.GetChildAtPoint(new Point(10, 10)); //the only way I've found to select the actual webBrowser
ppDisp = actualWebBrowser.ActiveXInstance; //try to pass actual browser reference to the new browser, but I can't notice any difference without this line

newTabWebBrowser.Navigate(bstrUrl); //navigate to the popup destination url

(newTabWebBrowser.ActiveXInstance as SHDocVw.WebBrowser).NewWindow3 += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow3EventHandler(Browser_NewWindow3); //attach this function to the new browser            

}
```

---

**ATTEMPTS**

I've tested it on some sites and the popup redirection on a new tab works but the new generated webBrowser seems to lost session authentication. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627776/webbrowser-control-and-cookies) previous question which seems to be close to mine but following the answer the problem persists.
Therefore I suppose this could be due to the original webBrowser's cookies, that I can access through actualWebBrowser.Document.Cookie but I wasn't able to trasfer to the new browser.

- I've tried `newTabWebBrowser.ActiveXInstance = actualWebBrowser.ActiveXInstance;` instead of `ppDisp = actualWebBrowser.ActiveXInstance;` which sounds very bad and can't compile because newTabWebBrowser.ActiveXInstance is read only.
- While `newTabWebBrowser.Document.Cookie = actualWebBrowser.Document.Cookie;` generate an error which doesn't block the application but skips my `Browser_NewWindow3()` function.
- I've also found `InternetSetCookie(url, cookie);` which has to be declared by `[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string Url, string Cookie);` Unfortunately I wasn't able to use these, maybe I miss some statements.

---

**QUESTION**

How can I force my new browser (inside new tab) to remember its "parent's" session/login information?

(*None even tried to answer. Please, notice me if I have posted this question in an incorrect way, or if exists another c# dedicated forum where I can post my question*)

---

**SCHEME:**

[image]